# Linux0.11 setup.s print message

Tags: linux, assembly

Here the Origin code of [setup.s](https://github.com/icecity96/Linux-0.11/blob/master/boot/setup.s).
and I was asked to print some message about cursor pos.So I modified the origin code as follow:

```
    .code16
# rewrite with AT&T syntax by falcon <wuzhangjin@gmail.com> at 081012
#
#   setup.s     (C) 1991 Linus Torvalds
#
# setup.s is responsible for getting the system data from the BIOS,
# and putting them into the appropriate places in system memory.
# both setup.s and system has been loaded by the bootblock.
#
# This code asks the bios for memory/disk/other parameters, and
# puts them in a "safe" place: 0x90000-0x901FF, ie where the
# boot-block used to be. It is then up to the protected mode
# system to read them from there before the area is overwritten
# for buffer-blocks.
#

# NOTE! These had better be the same as in bootsect.s!

    .equ INITSEG, 0x9000    # we move boot here - out of the way
    .equ SYSSEG, 0x1000 # system loaded at 0x10000 (65536).
    .equ SETUPSEG, 0x9020   # this is the current segment

    .global _start, begtext, begdata, begbss, endtext, enddata, endbss
    .text
    begtext:
    .data
    begdata:
    .bss
    begbss:
    .text

    ljmp $SETUPSEG, $_start
_start:
    mov %cs,%ax
    mov %ax,%ds
    mov %ax,%es
#
##print some message
#
    mov $0x03, %ah
    xor %bh, %bh
    int $0x10

    mov $30, %cx
    mov $0x000b,%bx
    mov $msg2,%bp
    mov $0x1301, %ax
    int $0x10
# ok, the read went well so we get current cursor position and save it for
# posterity.
    mov $INITSEG, %ax   # this is done in bootsect already, but...
    mov %ax, %ds
    mov $0x03, %ah  # read cursor pos
    xor %bh, %bh
    int $0x10       # save it in known place, con_init fetches
    mov %dx, %ds:0  # it from 0x90000.
# Get memory size (extended mem, kB)

    mov $0x88, %ah
    int $0x15
    mov %ax, %ds:2

# Get video-card data:

    mov $0x0f, %ah
    int $0x10
    mov %bx, %ds:4  # bh = display page
    mov %ax, %ds:6  # al = video mode, ah = window width

# check for EGA/VGA and some config parameters

    mov $0x12, %ah
    mov $0x10, %bl
    int $0x10
    mov %ax, %ds:8
    mov %bx, %ds:10
    mov %cx, %ds:12

# Get hd0 data

    mov $0x0000, %ax
    mov %ax, %ds
    lds %ds:4*0x41, %si
    mov $INITSEG, %ax
    mov %ax, %es
    mov $0x0080, %di
    mov $0x10, %cx
    rep
    movsb

# Get hd1 data

    mov $0x0000, %ax
    mov %ax, %ds
    lds %ds:4*0x46, %si
    mov $INITSEG, %ax
    mov %ax, %es
    mov $0x0090, %di
    mov $0x10, %cx
    rep
    movsb

## modify ds
    mov $INITSEG,%ax
    mov %ax,%ds
    mov $SETUPSEG,%ax
    mov %ax,%es

##show cursor pos:
    mov $0x03, %ah
    xor %bh,%bh
    int $0x10
    mov $11,%cx
    mov $0x000c,%bx
    mov $cur,%bp
    mov $0x1301,%ax
    int $0x10
##show detail
    mov %ds:0 ,%ax
    call print_hex
    call print_nl
l:
    jmp l
##
# Check that there IS a hd1 :-)

    mov $0x01500, %ax
    mov $0x81, %dl
    int $0x13
    jc  no_disk1
    cmp $3, %ah
    je  is_disk1
no_disk1:
    mov $INITSEG, %ax
    mov %ax, %es
    mov $0x0090, %di
    mov $0x10, %cx
    mov $0x00, %ax
    rep
    stosb
is_disk1:

# now we want to move to protected mode ...

    cli         # no interrupts allowed !

# first we move the system to it's rightful place

    mov $0x0000, %ax
    cld         # 'direction'=0, movs moves forward
do_move:
    mov %ax, %es    # destination segment
    add $0x1000, %ax
    cmp $0x9000, %ax
    jz  end_move
    mov %ax, %ds    # source segment
    sub %di, %di
    sub %si, %si
    mov     $0x8000, %cx
    rep
    movsw
    jmp do_move

# then we load the segment descriptors

end_move:
    mov $SETUPSEG, %ax  # right, forgot this at first. didn't work :-)
    mov %ax, %ds
    lidt    idt_48      # load idt with 0,0
    lgdt    gdt_48      # load gdt with whatever appropriate

# that was painless, now we enable A20

    #call   empty_8042  # 8042 is the keyboard controller
    #mov    $0xD1, %al  # command write
    #out    %al, $0x64
    #call   empty_8042
    #mov    $0xDF, %al  # A20 on
    #out    %al, $0x60
    #call   empty_8042
    inb     $0x92, %al  # open A20 line(Fast Gate A20).
    orb     $0b00000010, %al
    outb    %al, $0x92

# well, that went ok, I hope. Now we have to reprogram the interrupts :-(
# we put them right after the intel-reserved hardware interrupts, at
# int 0x20-0x2F. There they won't mess up anything. Sadly IBM really
# messed this up with the original PC, and they haven't been able to
# rectify it afterwards. Thus the bios puts interrupts at 0x08-0x0f,
# which is used for the internal hardware interrupts as well. We just
# have to reprogram the 8259's, and it isn't fun.

    mov $0x11, %al      # initialization sequence(ICW1)
                    # ICW4 needed(1),CASCADE mode,Level-triggered
    out %al, $0x20      # send it to 8259A-1
    .word   0x00eb,0x00eb       # jmp $+2, jmp $+2
    out %al, $0xA0      # and to 8259A-2
    .word   0x00eb,0x00eb
    mov $0x20, %al      # start of hardware int's (0x20)(ICW2)
    out %al, $0x21      # from 0x20-0x27
    .word   0x00eb,0x00eb
    mov $0x28, %al      # start of hardware int's 2 (0x28)
    out %al, $0xA1      # from 0x28-0x2F
    .word   0x00eb,0x00eb       #               IR 7654 3210
    mov $0x04, %al      # 8259-1 is master(0000 0100) --\
    out %al, $0x21      #               |
    .word   0x00eb,0x00eb       #            INT    /
    mov $0x02, %al      # 8259-2 is slave(       010 --> 2)
    out %al, $0xA1
    .word   0x00eb,0x00eb
    mov $0x01, %al      # 8086 mode for both
    out %al, $0x21
    .word   0x00eb,0x00eb
    out %al, $0xA1
    .word   0x00eb,0x00eb
    mov $0xFF, %al      # mask off all interrupts for now
    out %al, $0x21
    .word   0x00eb,0x00eb
    out %al, $0xA1

# well, that certainly wasn't fun :-(. Hopefully it works, and we don't
# need no steenking BIOS anyway (except for the initial loading :-).
# The BIOS-routine wants lots of unnecessary data, and it's less
# "interesting" anyway. This is how REAL programmers do it.
#
# Well, now's the time to actually move into protected mode. To make
# things as simple as possible, we do no register set-up or anything,
# we let the gnu-compiled 32-bit programs do that. We just jump to
# absolute address 0x00000, in 32-bit protected mode.
    #mov    $0x0001, %ax    # protected mode (PE) bit
    #lmsw   %ax     # This is it!
    mov %cr0, %eax  # get machine status(cr0|MSW)
    bts $0, %eax    # turn on the PE-bit
    mov %eax, %cr0  # protection enabled

                # segment-descriptor        (INDEX:TI:RPL)
    .equ    sel_cs0, 0x0008 # select for code segment 0 (  001:0 :00)
    ljmp    $sel_cs0, $0    # jmp offset 0 of code segment 0 in gdt

# This routine checks that the keyboard command queue is empty
# No timeout is used - if this hangs there is something wrong with
# the machine, and we probably couldn't proceed anyway.
empty_8042:
    .word   0x00eb,0x00eb
    in  $0x64, %al  # 8042 status port
    test    $2, %al     # is input buffer full?
    jnz empty_8042  # yes - loop
    ret

gdt:
    .word   0,0,0,0     # dummy

    .word   0x07FF      # 8Mb - limit=2047 (2048*4096=8Mb)
    .word   0x0000      # base address=0
    .word   0x9A00      # code read/exec
    .word   0x00C0      # granularity=4096, 386

    .word   0x07FF      # 8Mb - limit=2047 (2048*4096=8Mb)
    .word   0x0000      # base address=0
    .word   0x9200      # data read/write
    .word   0x00C0      # granularity=4096, 386

idt_48:
    .word   0           # idt limit=0
    .word   0,0         # idt base=0L

gdt_48:
    .word   0x800           # gdt limit=2048, 256 GDT entries
    .word   512+gdt, 0x9        # gdt base = 0X9xxxx,
    # 512+gdt is the real gdt after setup is moved to 0x9020 * 0x10
print_hex:
    mov $4,%cx
    mov %ax,%dx

print_digit:
    rol $4,%dx  #循环以使低4位用上，高4位移至低4位
    mov $0xe0f,%ax #ah ＝ 请求的功能值，al = 半个字节的掩码
    and %dl,%al
    add $0x30,%al
    cmp $0x3a,%al
    jl outp
    add $0x07,%al

outp:
    int $0x10
    loop print_digit
    ret
#打印回车换行
print_nl:
    mov $0xe0d,%ax
    int $0x10
    mov $0xa,%al
    int $0x10
    ret

msg2:
    .byte 13,10
    .ascii "Now we are in setup ..."
    .byte 13,10,13,10
    .org 508
cur:
    .ascii "Cursor POS:"
mem:
    .ascii "Memory SIZE:"
cyl:
    .ascii "KB"
    .byte 13,10,13,10
    .ascii "HD Info"
    .byte 13,10
    .ascii "Cylinders:"
head:
    .ascii "Headers:"
sect:
    .ascii "Secotrs:"
.text
endtext:
.data
enddata:
.bss
endbss:
```

and this work fine.It print the message:`Cursor pos:0E01`.If I delete the line 122-123(where is a endless loop,**`l:` `jmp l`**),that message won't be printed.I was confused with that.Anyone can tell me why.

Comment: Are those lines the `sub %di, %di` and `sub %si, %si` instructions? Because there's a specific reason for those instructions: they clear the `si` and `di` registers for the `rep movsw`. If you are referring to other lines, please post them.

Comment: @MargaretBloom those lines are `l:` and  `jmp l`

Comment: that's indeed weired. does INT10 have buffering or something like that? can the output be flushed? another thing: does the code (except that the hex value and the newline is not printed) work, if you remove the endless loop ?